# Cloudflare request with big data response

Tags: axios, cloudflare

The domain is linked via Cloudflare to my IP server.
There was a problem when I make a "get" request and get JSON with data more than 300 lines, it does not load, more precisely, it simply loads 50% of the data and remains in the download mode, the request is not executed.
If you directly make a request through ip:port, and not through the "domain/api", then everything works fine.